# Dynamic UILabel height depending content

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm populating an UILabel with JSON data and I want it to adjust its height to the content it loads. Also the rest of the labels in the view should move. How can I do this using Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autolayout. 
You can give priority to the label you load from the json and shrink other labels. 
This tutorial is a good place to start with auto layout - http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://nscookbook.com/2015/06/ios-programming-recipe-36-a-fixed-width-dynamic-height-scrollview-in-autolayout/
You can do that either in the storyboard or in the code

Answer (score 1):

I would consider putting the labels in a UIStackView if your app requires iOS 9+. If for some reason the labels aren't resizing properly when you change the text, you can force it by calling `[label sizeToFit];`.